# react-router-dom (v6) Routing not working in production while working in development

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router-dom, mern, azure-static-web-app

I have defined all my routes in `App.js` file, given below

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    {user && <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />}
    <Route path='/' element={<SignUp />} />
    <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
    <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Navigate replace to="/signin" />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The first  component is only rendered if there is a `user` object defined. It defines the path `/dashboard` and renders the `Dashboard` component.

The second `<Route>` component defines the path `/` and renders the `SignUp` component.

The third `<Route>` component defines the path `/signin` and renders the `Signin` component.

The fourth `<Route>` component also defines the path `/dashboard`, but in this case, it uses the `Navigate` component to redirect the user to the `/signin` path. The replace attribute is used to replace the current route in the history stack, and the to attribute is used to define the path to redirect to.

In development it was working fine with all the routing but when deployed to Azure Static Web Apps it is showing 404 page not found. I have attached the image below which is for the URL `https://agreeable-coast-05611e900.2.azurestaticapps.net/dashboard`

[404: Not found page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaNMe.png)

I have hosted all the projects in GitHub feel free to check it out.

Server - https://github.com/Somanyu/finproject-server

Client - https://github.com/Somanyu/finproject-client

Comment: The server should be configured to serve the root index.html file for all page requests into the React app. This is so the React app is mounted and can handle matching and rendering the appropriate route. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) for a general idea how different server environments are configured/setup/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The routing problem has been fixed using `staticwebapps.config.json`.

Comment: @Protonic Post your solution as an answer so that it can help other community members with the same type of issue.

Comment: @Protonic how did you solved it please answer you question so that everyone can benefit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Solution]**

The issue was because of the `staticwebapps.config.json` file which is a configuration file used by Azure Static Web Apps. It contains settings that configure the behavior of the static web app when it's deployed and running on the Azure platform.

As ReactJS is a single-page application (SPA), and all navigation is handled by JavaScript. By default, if a user navigates to a non-existent route, the server would return a 404 error. With this setting, Azure ensures that all navigation requests get rewritten to the `index.html` file, which will then load the React app and handle the routing.

So you must add `navigationFallback` config to the `staticwebapps.config.json` which tells Azure to rewrite all navigation requests to the index.html file, which is the entry point of your React app.

**staticwebapps.config.json file**

```json
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  },
  "globalHeaders": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://<YOUR PROJECT>.azurewebsites.net",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
  }
}
```